# How to make a custom TextView with fading text?

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, marquee

I want to make a custom `TextView` with fading text like the marquee's fading effect. Here is my code: It doesn't work.

```
    public class FadeTextView extends TextView {

    private Paint mShaderPaint;
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private LinearGradient mShader;
    private RectF mFadingRect;

    public FadeTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public FadeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public FadeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mShaderPaint = new Paint();
        mShader = new LinearGradient(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom(), 0x7FFFFFFF, 0x00FFFFFF,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        mShaderPaint.setShader(mShader);
        mShaderPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        canvas.drawRect(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom(), mShaderPaint);
    }
}
```

Even I tried to just draw a text, it also failed:

```
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setTextSize(16);
    canvas.drawText("test", getLeft(), getTop(), paint);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't want the animation, just want the fading edge for the Text which is too long. Thanks!

Comment: maybe on your `onDraw` you draw two images on left and right that Simi-transparent

Comment: @DarkNeo: You resolved your issue or not?

Comment: Have any of you resolved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you can make the fade animation using xml also as following
(anim/alpha.xml) put it into
 **res/anim/alpha.xml**

```
 <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromAlpha="0.0"
  android:toAlpha="1.0"
  android:duration="3000" />
```

**in java file**

```
   private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    TextView l=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);
   }
```

for more detail you can check this [animated splash screen](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-fancy-animated-splash-screen/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want the animation, just want the fading edge for the Text which is too long. Thanks!